# xslt check multiple conditions and then divide value by attribute attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, conditional-statements

I'm using `Choose` and `When` inside a `for-each` to do multiple condition checks

For example, the following simply checks the sum of a certain node and checks if the value is less than 50

```
<xsl:when test="sum(scores/score) &lt; 50">
    <td>
       <xsl:text>A1</xsl:text>        
    </td>
</xsl:when>
```

I have five of these and they run through fine, except the last one which does multiple checks.

I need to check if both these conditions are met

- The sum is greater than a certain number, say 20
- The attribute `@mandatory` for `score` equals `'True'` **for at least one `score`**

If both of these conditions are met, I need to run another condition

- divide the value of `score` by another attribute `weight`
- if the result is less than 0.5 the print the result into the table using `<xsl:text>`

I have tried

```
<xsl:when test="sum(scores/score) &gt; 20 and @mandatory='True'">
    <td>
       <xsl:text>F1</xsl:text>        
    </td>
</xsl:when
```

This fails to even to do the second check of whether `mandatory` equals `True`
The result is the same even if I use the path `scores/score/@mandatory`

I've tried moving the second condition to an `if` nested inside the `when` but that has failed as well

```
<xsl:when test="sum(scores/score) &gt; 20">
<xsl:if test="@mandatory='True'"                 // even if I use scores/score/@mandatory
    <td>
       <xsl:text>F1</xsl:text>        
    </td>
</xsl:when
```

So basically it's failing at the first hurdle. My other condition which I want to implement is divide `scores/score` by `scores/score/@weight`

I'm thinking of but haven't been able to get there to even play with it

```
<xsl:if test="(scores/score) div (scores/score/@weight) &lt; 0.5">
     // print result into table
</xsl:if>
```

Here is some sample xml relevant to the xslt

```
 <scores>
          <score no="1" weight="10" mandatory="False">8</score>
          <score no="2" weight="20" mandatory="True">13</score>
 </scores>
```

Just an extra note. A `scores` node may have more than two `score` elements. Also there doesn't necessarily have to be a `mandatory` attribute with a `"True"` value, likewise there may be multiple elements with a `mandatory="true"` attribute.

The following xml samples are valid

Multiple `mandatory="true"`

```
 <scores>
          <score no="1" weight="10" mandatory="False">8</score>
          <score no="2" weight="20" mandatory="True">13</score>
          <score no="3" weight="50" mandatory="True">35</score>
 </scores>
```

No `mandatory="true"`

```
 <scores>
          <score no="1" weight="10" mandatory="False">8</score>
          <score no="2" weight="20" mandatory="False">13</score>
          <score no="3" weight="50" mandatory="False">35</score>
 </scores>
```

Comment: *"The attribute `@mandatory` for `score` equals `'True'`"*. Is this condition has to be: a. met by all `score` or b. met by at least one `score`?

Comment: @har07 Thanks for mentioning this, I've added the related business logic to the question. The condition has to be met by at least one score

Comment: Alright, that part is clear now, thanks. Next, *"if the result is less than 0.5 ..."*. Again, is this has to be true for all `score`/`weight` ratio, or at least one ?

Comment: @har07 At least once for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the context element is parent of `scores`, then the following XPath expression should work to test for the first two bulleted conditions :

```
sum(scores/score) &gt; 20 and scores/score/@mandatory='True'
```

And then the next two bulleted conditions can be translated into XPath as follow :

```
scores/score[. div @weight &lt; 0.5]
```

**Demo : http://xsltransform.net/bFN1ya7**

Comment: Interestingly I tried the first expression before but couldn't to get it workng. Moving it to the top of the `<xsl:when>` and now that's all good. My problem is dividing the `score` and `@weight` should be a sub condition of the first expression. So basically after checking if it is greater than 20 and `@mandatory = True` Then it should do the division between the `score` and the `@weight`

Comment: If i append the first expression with another `and` then put the second expression. It doesn't seem to evaluate the expression. If I nest an `<xsl:If test="scores/score[. div @weight &lt; 0.5]"` inside the `when` then it seems to perform the expression but doesn't print anything. Even though the `<xsl:text` is nested inside the `<xsl:if>`

Comment: Got it!
There was a simple spelling mistake in one of the node names. Thanks so much. I'll post the code later tonight. Thanks again. I ended up doing it on one line but may move it to a nested `<xsl:if>` for readability

Comment: this is the one liner `<xsl:when test="sum(scores/score) &gt; 20 and scores/score/@mandatory='True' and scores/score[. div @weight &lt; 0.5]">`